# When does autocommit take place when many rows are inserted as a single statement?

Tags: mysql, insert, mysql-5.7

I have some problems with performance of insertion of about 50000 rows into a table. As an optimization it's advised to start a transaction explicitly to avoid committing on each row. However, I insert all rows in one statement, not in 50000 statements.

So I wonder, when AUTOCOMMIT mode is on, when does a commit occurs when I insert a lot of rows in single statement - after all 50000 rows are inserted or after each row is added into a table.

In other words, is this following code

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6);
```

is equivalent to the code

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6);
COMMIT
```

or maybe it actually means:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 2);
COMMIT
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (3, 4);
COMMIT
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (5, 6);
COMMIT
```

can you tell me?

Also, it's worth mentioning, that I have tried to insert not all 50000 rows as a single statement, but no more than 5000 rows at once (without explicit transactions, but also 5000 rows as a single statement), and I got controversial result - on some tables it got better about 6 times, while on others it got worse about twice, and on the whole, all got to work slower. I deemed that a commit occurs only after the whole statement is executed, but now I have doubts concerning it.

Comment: (When you have autocommit), one statement, one commit. There can't be 3 commits for a single statement.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html : *"... so MySQL **does a commit after each SQL statement** if that statement did not return an error."*

Comment: Beyond 1000 rows at a time, you get into diminishing returns, and into other issues, especially with replication.  I have often seen 10x.